# Symfony 2 application without CSS content in OVH server?

Tags: css, deployment, symfony, setup-deployment, web-deployment

I searched almost two days for a solution but really i cant untill now, In short I deployed my site to a OVH server with filezilla  following the steps in this tutorial [here](http://pilvee.com/blog/deploiement-symfony2/)

After deployment I find that my site works fine but without CSS content in FF and Chrome, so when I check in firebug I find all CSS styles are loaded correctly but empty without content,also JS file are loaded  with content and all images too.In IE I have the style that works fine but no image is loaded ??I work on Ubuntu and I use a Virtual Machine to use IE...

I almost did everything, I cleared the cache and I changed the access rights of all files, I specify for files => 705, the CSS and JS => 604,finally I put everything to 777 but still no change ...

An idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from assetic : when css and js files get minified and concatenated using closure or yui css, .. java is called to execute jar code contained in .jar files.

On OVH shared hosting servers you don't have java available, so the output file that symfony generates when you run the assetic dump command is actually empty (hence your empty css + js files).

You should only minify those files (assetic dump) on your local server and then upload the output to your server. Don't run assetic dump on your production server! (well at least with an OVH shared hosting)

Comment: I agree,I will try to do,in the same time i have just the CSS files are emplty but JS files are not;also I have another question when I used my server OVH in the first,I made a mistake,I removed all files in server just I keeped "www"??

Comment: Depending on which plan you're using, you are allowed to create subdomains and have ssh access or not. If you have limited access, you can use ftp to put symfony into a new /sf folder for instance. Then using the webftp interface you should be able to create a symbolic link from /www to /sf/web

Comment: ,I'm working on it,but I have a very important question,when I used OVH server in my first time,I removed all filles and .htaccess too in my server Ikeeped only the folder "www",I made a masetake,so is this going to affect my symfony project 2 and site security or not?

Comment: Just set back a new .htaccess file - symfony provides one so if you copy everything to your server it will have one. You might need to also set the PHP version to be at least 5.3 by adding "SetEnv PHP_VER 5_4" to your .htaccess (or create a new one for that in the root of the server, you then have two: one in the root and one in www/ which is a symbolic link to /sf/web/ )

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and the culprit turned out to be an outdated version of the PCRE regular expression library that was compiled into the CentOS flavor of PHP. Try to run the command `php -i` or use the `phpinfo()` function and check if your version of the PCRE is 7.0 or newer. If it's older, it doesn't support the shorthand version of named capture groups.

To fix this, try to update **assetic** to a newer version that uses the more compatible longer version of named capture groups. If you can't do this, you can modify the offending file `/vendor/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/BaseCssFilter.php` directly. Just replace all occurences of `(?<paramname>` with `(?P<paramname>`.

Note that the correct way would be to override this file instead of modifying it directly in the `vendors` directory.

Comment: Cool, I just stumbled into the same problem again, googled for a solution and found my own answer. Thanks, my past self!